# Renamed package in Android Studio and now Rebuild Project is failing

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I refactored my project from com.oldname.appname to com.newname.appname in Android Studio, then updated the applicationId and namespace values in build.gradle, did a Build->Clean Project and Build->Rebuild Project, but for some reason the `tools:context=".MainActivity">` in my layouts says it's an unresolved class. The IDE is also auto-importing `import com.oldname.appname.R`, which results in "Unresolved reference: oldname" error during build.

Comment: Did you move your MainActivity into the new package name? If not, you'll have to use a fully qualified name in your XML files that reference it. The lone `.` prefix is shorthand for classes whose package matches the application ID. For the resources, you'll have to do find and replace.

Comment: Yeah, the refactor appears to have moved all files into the com.newname.appname package.

Answer (score 0):

The below step **resolve** my problem.

1. open any **activity class** file
2. now, hover over **package name** in code which is first line of your code.
3. click change file's package to **com.newname.appname**

```kotlin
    package com.oldname.appname
```

to

```kotlin
    package com.newname.appname
```

Comment: The refactor already changed the package name in my code to com.newname.appname. :(

Comment: How do you refracted your project?

Comment: When I right-clicked on the name of the package, I said Refactor->Rename. The IDE is supposed to capture all places where the name is and change it automatically, but the fact that it's auto-importing com.oldname.appname.R means it must still have that package name somewhere.